# No Steam in multiverse repository

Tags: 20.04, package-management, wine, steam

Today I was trying to install steam. Multiverse repository is available from the beginning. But using command `sudo apt install steam` what I get is

```
sudo apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
```

I've been trying to install steam-installer, but it requires `steam` so it's not working.

I tried with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` but also with no luck.

Of course I used `sudo apt update` but it also didn't help.

What should I do? Very similar problems appeared when I tried to install wine and I also couldn't do it.

Here's what I get from `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe multiverse restricted main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe multiverse restricted main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports universe multiverse restricted main
```

Comment: Please add `sudp apt update` to your question?

Comment: @N0rbert Well, I did recreate sources.list and nothing has changed unfortunately

Comment: Are you running x86_64? Also please run `sudo apt-get update` and add `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question or pastebin.

Comment: @nobody Of course I did sudo apt update but it didnt help

Comment: @N0rbert edited my question with result of your command

Comment: @N0rbert changing server to Main also didn't help

Comment: @N0rbert and yes, I run x86_64 with i386 added

Comment: For me it seems that you have errors during `sudo apt-get update` operation, so system uses old package lists. Please share full complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6:i386` .

Comment: @N0rbert here you are: https://pastebin.com/GJrz1cU9

Comment: Please clear the lists with `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123863/discussion-between-thematt-and-n0rbert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During chat session we have discovered the following moments:

1. For some reason `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` did not worked for first time. So we ran it multiple times.
2. For reproducible results we removed local software lists by `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.
3. We discovered that the system had two different versions of libc6 packages for amd64 (*2.31-0ubuntu9.2* from official repository) and i386 (*2.31-0ubuntu9.3* from some local source), so we installed correct versions by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:i386=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
   ```
4. Finally we installed Steam by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   sudo aptitude install steam:i386
   ```